# STE availability in Entity Framework 6

Tags: entity-framework, self-tracking-entities, entity-framework-6

I can't find information if there will be support for STE (self tracking entities) in Entity Framework 6. I would appreciate if anybody know the answer.

I was looking at EF site but there is no word about STE.

Thank you.